# d3 - disable scrolling when zooming with mouse wheel?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming, mousewheel

I am using the code from the [Brush & Zoom line chart block](https://bl.ocks.org/EfratVil/92f894ac0ba265192411e73f633a3e2f).

What I notice, though, is that if the graph is fully zoomed out (like it is when originally viewing the graph) and I place my mouse cursor over the graph and spin the mouse wheel down (which would normally zoom out), it scrolls the browser window down.

Is there a way in d3 to basically say, "Anytime the mouse is over the SVG, wheel scrolling should NOT scroll the browser window?"

Answer (score 0):

You may try to set overscroll-behavior to "none" on svg. It is supported in Chrome/Edge/Firefox, but unfortunately not on Safari.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue like this:

FIRST SOLUTION (NOT BAD)
[image]
To sum up, We can not disable the main scroll scrolling. But we may add overflow to the div which can be Zoom In/Out and just hide the scrolls by changing height and width to 0.

```
.zoom-works {
   overflow: auto;
   &::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
   }
}
```

SECOND SOLUTION(GOOD)

Just `preventDefault` solves the issue. I am an Angular developer and have solved it like this(You do not need any HTML/CSS tricks):

```
@HostListener('mousewheel', ['$event']) onMousewheel(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
}
```